# JAXB flatten list of entities when marshalling

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jaxb

I'm using JPA/Hibernate as my persistence framework, and I have the following entity hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
@XmlRootElement(name = "nodeMap")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NodeMapDTO {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ipAddresses")
    @XmlElement(name = "ipAddress")
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
    private List<IPAddressDTO> ipAddresses;

    [...]
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "node_ip_address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IPAddressDTO {

    @Column(name = "ip_address")
    private String ipAddress;

    [...]
}
```

When I convert a NodeMapDTO into XML, I get the following result:

```
<nodeMap>
   <ipAddresses>
      <ipAddress>
         <ipAddress>192.59.233.20</ipAddress>
      </ipAddress>
   </ipAddresses>
</nodeMap>
```

But I want it to be:

```
<nodeMap>
   <ipAddresses>
      <ipAddress>192.59.233.20</ipAddress>
   </ipAddresses>
</nodeMap>
```

I unfortunately need to have my `ipAddresses` field be a list of `IPAddressDTO`s instead of `String`s because otherwise I can't use the @OneToMany annotation (and no I don't want to use @ElementCollection for performance reasons).

I'd also like to try to do this without having to create any extra wrapper classes. I think if I create a wrapper class for the `List<IPAddressDTO> ipAddresses` field, my Hibernate annotations won't work and it'll just make the code much more complex than it needs to be.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate field `ipAddress` with [`@XmlValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html).

Here is a full [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(NodeMapDTO.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(new NodeMapDTO(new IPAddressDTO("192.59.233.20")), System.out);
    }
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "nodeMap")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NodeMapDTO {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ipAddresses")
    @XmlElement(name = "ipAddress")
    private List<IPAddressDTO> ipAddresses;

    NodeMapDTO() {
    }
    NodeMapDTO(IPAddressDTO... ipAddresses) {
        this.ipAddresses = Arrays.asList(ipAddresses);
    }
}
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IPAddressDTO {
    @XmlValue
    private String ipAddress;

    IPAddressDTO() {
    }
    IPAddressDTO(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }
}
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<nodeMap>
    <ipAddresses>
        <ipAddress>192.59.233.20</ipAddress>
    </ipAddresses>
</nodeMap>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you! In case others are curious, I also had to add a @JsonValue annotation on top of the getter for the IPAddressDTO.ipAddress field in order to get this to work for JSON.